Changing the Order of Integration for a Triple Integral
Consider the three-dimensional solid bounded by the region $$\mathcal R = \{(x, y, z) \mid y^3 \leq x \leq y, \, z \leq y \leq \sqrt z, \text{ and } 0 \leq z \leq 1\}.$$ By definition, the volume of this three-dimensional solid is the triple integral $$\int_0^1 \int_z^{\sqrt z} \int_{y^3}^y 1 \, dx \, dy \,dz = \frac 1 {20}.$$ Computing this iterated integral is a simple application of the Power Rule and the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.
By Fubini's Theorem, the volume of this three-dimensional solid can be calculated using any order of integration, hence there exist real univariate (possibly piecewise-defined) functions $f_1(x, z),$ $f_2(x, z),$ $g_1(z),$ and $g_2(z)$ such that $$\int_0^1 \int_{g_1(z)}^{g_2(z)} \int_{f_1(x, z)}^{f_2(x, z)} 1 \, dy \, dx \, dz = \frac 1 {20}.$$ But trying to determine these functions proves non-trivial (ostensibly because the region is not vertically or horizontally simple). Going purely on instinct and the inequalities that define the region, it seems that the following hold.
\begin{align*}
\max\{x, z\} &\leq y \leq \min\{x^{1/3}, z^{1/2}\} \\
z^3 &\leq x \leq z^{1/2} \\
0 &\leq z \leq 1
\end{align*}
Unfortunately, even proceeding by cases, it is not clear to me how to resolve the inequality in $y$: indeed, if $x \geq z,$ then there are two cases when $x^{1/3} \geq z^{1/2}$ and when $x^{1/3} \leq z^{1/2}.$ But already, the sum of the two resulting triple integrals exceeds the known value, so this cannot be correct.
Ultimately, I am seeking a (purely algebraic) approach to resolving the triple integral with the order of integration $dy \, dx \, dz.$ I would be grateful for any thoughtful feedback or commentary. Thanks for your time and consideration.

"Instinct" in this case needs to mean drawing pictures. If you can't visualize it you can't do it.

"I am seeking a (purely algebraic) approach to resolving the triple integral" -- You seek an exercise in pain. The pictures you draw to visualize these domains are not just a teaching tool, they are something you're meant to utilize to understand how to set up the bounds correctly. You cannot handle multiple integrals well without a good, visual grasp of the shapes you're integrating over: full stop.

@NinadMunshi, bearing in mind the vast amount of brilliant mathematics in the canon, your assertion is patently false. I agree that visuals can be useful, but there are obvious limitations to this approach. I encourage you to draw the three planar regions encoded by this integral and see for yourself that the situation is quite subtle.

@PrincessEev, I disagree wholeheartedly with your last statement. One of the best tools that students of mathematics can learn is algebra. Best of luck visualizing shapes in any Euclidean space with dimension larger than three. We can only envision so much before it is necessary to understand the algebra of the inequalities that define a hypersurface.

Denote your integral by $I$. It can be split into four integrals, each of which has iterated limits.
You can rewrite the last condition as
$$\max\{x,z\}\le y\le \min\{x^{1/3},z^{1/2}\}$$
$$\left(0\le y\le \min\{x^{1/3},z^{1/2}\}\right)\setminus \left(0\le y\le \max\{x,z\}\right).$$ Call $I_1$ the integral over the first region, and $I_2$ the integral over the second region. Then $I=I_1-I_2$.
Basically, we want to break the $xz$ plane, where we have the inequality $z^3\le x\le z^{1/2}$, into the two subregions, $z^3\le x\le z^{3/2}$ and $z^{3/2}\le x\le z^{1/2}$. Then the min/max bit is just one of the inputs on each subregion.
$$I_1=\int_0^1 \int_{z^3}^{z^{1/2}}\int_0^{\min\{x^{1/3},z^{1/2}\}}1\,dydxdz$$
$$=\int_0^1 \int_{z^3}^{z^{3/2}}\int_0^{\min\{x^{1/3},z^{1/2}\}}1\,dydxdz+\int_0^1 \int_{z^{3/2}}^{z^{1/2}}\int_0^{\min\{x^{1/3},z^{1/2}\}}1\,dydxdz$$
$$=\int_0^1 \int_{z^3}^{z^{3/2}}\int_0^{x^{1/3}}1\,dydxdz+\int_0^1 \int_{z^{3/2}}^{z^{1/2}}\int_0^{z^{1/2}}1\,dydxdz$$
Similarly, for $I_2$ we split the $xz$ plane at $x=z$, yielding
$$I_2 = \int_0^1 \int_{z^3}^{z^{1/2}}\int_0^{\max\{x,z\}}1\,dydxdz$$
$$=\int_0^1 \int_{z^3}^{z}\int_0^{\max\{x,z\}}1\,dydxdz+\int_0^1 \int_{z}^{z^{1/2}}\int_0^{\max\{x,z\}}1\,dydxdz$$
$$=\int_0^1 \int_{z^3}^{z}\int_0^{z}1\,dydxdz+\int_0^1 \int_{z}^{z^{1/2}}\int_0^{x}1\,dydxdz$$
Indeed, $I_1=\frac{4}{15}$ and $I_2=\frac{13}{60}$, so $I=\frac{1}{20}$, as you wanted.

Beautiful solution. Thank you for resolving my question!
